# find the latest rcord from a row in oracle script

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have the below structure for my table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE datatable
(
   "DT_ID"                NUMBER (10, 0),
   "ASSIGNED"             NUMBER (1, 0) DEFAULT 0,
   "ASSIGNED_DATE_TIME"   DATE,
   "ASSIGNED_BY"          VARCHAR2 (7 BYTE),
   "ACCEPTED"             NUMBER (1, 0) DEFAULT 0,
   "ACCEPTED_DATE_TIME"   DATE,
   "ACCEPTED_BY"          VARCHAR2 (7 BYTE),
   "REJECTED"             NUMBER (1, 0) DEFAULT 0,
   "REJECTED_DATE_TIME"   DATE,
   "REJECTED_BY"          VARCHAR2 (7 BYTE)
);
```

I need to find the latest action based on the date and need to insert it into a new table.

insert into newTable(ID, ACTION_USER, DATE ) values (DT_ID , here i need to check the order of
ACCEPTED_DATE_TIME,REJECTED_DATE_TIME,ASSIGNED_DATE_TIME  and want to find out the latest action and the corresponding owner(xxxxxx_BY) field , the corresponding datetime as assigned_date_time) to be inserted..

For example if `REJECTED_DATE_TIME` has the latest date then rejected_by field = action_user columns value.

Comment: you need to edit your question and show sample data for your table, and expected output.  Best if you setup the example in sqlfiddle.com and post the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GREATEST` and a `CASE` expression:

```sql
INSERT INTO newTable(id, action_user, action_date)
SELECT DT_ID,
       CASE GREATEST(assigned_date_time, accepted_date_time, rejected_date_time)
       WHEN rejected_date_time
       THEN rejected_by
       WHEN accepted_date_time
       THEN accepted_by
       WHEN assigned_date_time
       THEN assigned_by
       END,
       GREATEST(assigned_date_time, accepted_date_time, rejected_date_time)
FROM   datatable;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE datatable
(
   "DT_ID"                NUMBER (10, 0),
   "ASSIGNED"             NUMBER (1, 0) DEFAULT 0,
   "ASSIGNED_DATE_TIME"   DATE,
   "ASSIGNED_BY"          VARCHAR2 (7 BYTE),
   "ACCEPTED"             NUMBER (1, 0) DEFAULT 0,
   "ACCEPTED_DATE_TIME"   DATE,
   "ACCEPTED_BY"          VARCHAR2 (7 BYTE),
   "REJECTED"             NUMBER (1, 0) DEFAULT 0,
   "REJECTED_DATE_TIME"   DATE,
   "REJECTED_BY"          VARCHAR2 (7 BYTE)
);

INSERT INTO dataTable
SELECT 1, 0, DATE '2023-01-01', 'Alice', 1, DATE '2023-02-01', 'Betty', 2, DATE '2023-03-01', 'Carol' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE newTable(
  id          NUMBER(10,0),
  action_user VARCHAR2(7 BYTE),
  action_date DATE
);
```

Then, after the insert, the table contains:

| ID | ACTION_USER | ACTION_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Carol | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n0cYFY1l)

---

#### Update:

If you can have `NULL` values in the column then also use `COALESCE` and coalesce the values to a date literal that is guaranteed to be earlier than any other value in your table:

```sql
INSERT INTO newTable(id, action_user, action_date )
SELECT DT_ID,
       CASE GREATEST(
              COALESCE(assigned_date_time, DATE '1900-01-01'),
              COALESCE(accepted_date_time, DATE '1900-01-01'),
              COALESCE(rejected_date_time, DATE '1900-01-01')
            )
       WHEN COALESCE(rejected_date_time, DATE '1900-01-01')
       THEN rejected_by
       WHEN COALESCE(accepted_date_time, DATE '1900-01-01')
       THEN accepted_by
       WHEN COALESCE(assigned_date_time, DATE '1900-01-01')
       THEN assigned_by
       END,
       CASE GREATEST(
              COALESCE(assigned_date_time, DATE '1900-01-01'),
              COALESCE(accepted_date_time, DATE '1900-01-01'),
              COALESCE(rejected_date_time, DATE '1900-01-01')
            )
       WHEN COALESCE(rejected_date_time, DATE '1900-01-01')
       THEN rejected_date_time
       WHEN COALESCE(accepted_date_time, DATE '1900-01-01')
       THEN accepted_date_time
       WHEN COALESCE(assigned_date_time, DATE '1900-01-01')
       THEN assigned_date_time
       END
FROM   datatable;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE datatable
(
   "DT_ID"                NUMBER (10, 0),
   "ASSIGNED"             NUMBER (1, 0) DEFAULT 0,
   "ASSIGNED_DATE_TIME"   DATE,
   "ASSIGNED_BY"          VARCHAR2 (7 BYTE),
   "ACCEPTED"             NUMBER (1, 0) DEFAULT 0,
   "ACCEPTED_DATE_TIME"   DATE,
   "ACCEPTED_BY"          VARCHAR2 (7 BYTE),
   "REJECTED"             NUMBER (1, 0) DEFAULT 0,
   "REJECTED_DATE_TIME"   DATE,
   "REJECTED_BY"          VARCHAR2 (7 BYTE)
);

INSERT INTO dataTable
SELECT 1, 0, DATE '2023-01-01', 'Alice', 1, DATE '2023-02-01', 'Betty', 2, DATE '2023-03-01', 'Carol' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 0, DATE '2023-03-01', 'Debra', NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, DATE '2023-01-01', 'Emily' FROM DUAL

CREATE TABLE newTable(
  id          NUMBER(10,0),
  action_user VARCHAR2(7 BYTE),
  action_date DATE
);
```

Then, after the insert, the table contains:

| ID | ACTION_USER | ACTION_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Carol | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | Debra | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/trZDcBjS)

Comment: it is possible to have null values in the date and corresponding user fields also..i get null in that case.  SELECT 1, 0, DATE '2023-01-01', 'Alice', 1, DATE '2023-02-01', 'Betty', 2, null, null FROM DUAL this one gives nulll

Comment: .that means except id all are nullable fields.that means except id all are nullable fields

Comment: INSERT INTO dataTable
SELECT 1, 0, DATE '2023-01-01', 'Alice',  2, null, null,1, DATE '2024-04-04', 'Betty' FROM DUAL....if i use coalesce i get wrong result....here i am expecting 2024-04-04 as the greatest but this doesnt work with greatest(coalesce()

Comment: GREATEST(COALESCE(assigned_date_time, accepted_date_time, rejected_date_time))  is what i have used

Comment: @coder11b Updated - use `COALESCE` on each item and coalesce them with a date literal that is going to be earlier than any other value in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You could unpivot with `cross apply`, then aggregate the resultset to retrieve the latest action date per row, while `keep`ing the corresponding user.

```
insert into newtable (dt_id, action_user, action_date_time)
select d.dt_id,
    max(x.action_user) keep(dense_rank last order by x.action_date_time),
    max(x.action_date_time)
from datatable d
cross apply (
    select d.assigned_date_time action_date_time, d.assigned_by action_user from dual
    union all select d.accepted_date_time, d.accepted_by from dual
    union all select d.rejected_date_time, d.rejected_by from dual
) x
group by d.dt_id
```

Comment: i am looking to get the exact number of rows, if i have 10 records in my datatable i need the sam number of record in my new tabli am afraind the action user group by condition will not give me the result...the user can repeat

Comment: @coder11b: ah, I think I understand what you are saying. I updated my answer. It would have been easier if you had provided sample data and desired results in the question